# error: no matching function for call to 'getline'

Tags: c++, header, getline

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    //initializing two string

     string s2,s1="hello";

     cout<<s2<<s1;

     cout<<endl;
     //transferring(copying) data from s1 to s2 
       getline(s1,s2);

     cout<<s2<<s1;
}
```

Comment: are you guessing how `getline` works or are you using some reference?

Comment: What's unclear about the error? There is no `std::getline` function that takes 2 `std::string` arguments. If you wanted to do what you wrote about in the comment: "_transferring(copying) data from s1 to s2_", simple `s2 = s1;` would do that.

Comment: Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Also, as written, you are only initializing one string, `s1="hello"`. To initialize them both to "hello" you'd write `std::string s1="hello", s2="hello";`

Comment: can someone explain the thing happens during getline(cin,str), i was assuming that, according to it , the content from cin stream get transferred to str. I was right or wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by the fact that there is no `getline` that would accept two strings as parameters.

To "transfer" or copy data from `s1` to `s2` you write

```
s2 = s1;
```

It is unclear why you think you need `getline`. The method `getline` is for different purpose about which you can read eg [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).

Answer (score 0):

You are using getline wrong, please take a look at: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/

The getline function takes 2 parameters (a Istream and a string, instead of two times a string), that is the reason why you get the error.

If you just want to copy a string, you can use the following code:

```
std::string s1 = "myString";
std::string s2 = s1;
```